# Should I use animated objects or use the physics engine on iOS scenes with lots of rigidbodies?

Tags: physics, unity, animation, ios

I have a scene with lots of houses and other objects. These objects will be bombarded from the sky. How to handle these kind of settings having in mind that you want the physics to be as realistic as possible.

In Unity3D, if I set all the objects with isKinematic=true and on collision I set it to false, then the physics isn't as realistic as I want it to be... Can you have these kind of scenes on iPhone? Should I have animated objects? I really don't know what is the best practice in this kind of scenes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with the kinematic object is that physics engine doesn't check if 2 kinematic object have collision and even if it collide with a dynamic object there won't be any change in kinematic object's speed, so basically you have to set all your game objects as dynamic, on the other hand you have to define all your objects as simple as possible for performance issue, you have to use only rects and ellipses, and at most triangles, and there are too many games with your base concept available in iphone now (remember `angry birds`?)